# extracting data from a html form and comparing to a field in the database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying  to get this right, but it does not work. I can retrieve all the data from the database, but I wanted to retrieve a jobname from a html form which the user input in the form and a location also input in the form by the user and compare these texts with the jobname and location field on a table on the database. I know it sounds confusing, but here is my code that does nothing:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
ob_start();
$host=""; // Host name 
$username= ""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$job=$_POST['jobName'];
$mylocation=$_POST['location'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$job = stripslashes($job);
$mylocation = stripslashes($mylocation);
$job = mysql_real_escape_string($job);
$mylocation = mysql_real_escape_string($mylocation);

$sql="SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name." WHERE jobName='".$job."' and      location='".$mylocation."';";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();
?>
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">jobName</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">jobType</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Location</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Description</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Contact</font></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$job=mysql_result($result,$i,"jobName");
$type=mysql_result($result,$i,"jobType");
$myLocation=mysql_result($result,$i,"location");
$desc=mysql_result($result,$i,"description");
$cont=mysql_result($result,$i,"contact");
?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $job; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $type; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $myLocation; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $desc; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $cont; ?></font></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I just need a good tutorial to help me out although nothing I researched up to now helped me out, maybe if I can get an example code stating a similar issue, or a helping hand explaining where I am going wrong on this code. I appreciate it.

Comment: what error you are facing..??

Comment: Btw you have a syntax error: mysql_numrows it should be mysql_num_rows

Comment: try just `while ($num) {` no need of `$i`

Answer (score 0):

You need a HTML form on this, or other page pointing to this one.
Should look something like

```
<form method="post" action="file-above.php" (leave action attribute empty if it's in the same file)>
 <input type="text" name="jobName" />
 <input type="text" name="location" />
</form>
```

Code above is just to show you how the things should work, it isn't complete.

Comment: Seems like a good advice; need a submit-button there as well ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I have this piece of code on another page where I have this form and the user can input the text and when the user presses submit, this code I publish handles it, but still it does not work and when I press submit, it displays a blank page even though I have the data on the database

Comment: try print_r($_post); just for debug purpose. and print_r result from database too... and see what is missing?